# Where and how I can calculate and simulate PCB antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna

For example, if have inverted "F" PCB antenna and I need use it in my PCB project to 2.4 GHz (for ESP32). Of course, I can use calculated cases, but I want learn how it’s calculated and simulated.

My question is how can I calculate the values in this table?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Sonnet Lite for simulating antenna impedance. Don't have a good way of calculating, it's more of an trail and error. If you have a good reference design to start with it's normally just some tweaking that's needed.
https://www.sonnetsoftware.com/products/lite/

For F-antenna it is the feeding point position that's important, adjusting D5/D6. together with the total length.